# Cannot find name 'Landbot'. Did you mean '_landbot'?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I am trying to integrate Landbot into my React.js with typescript application. I am following this [doc] [1](https://static.landbot.io/landbot-3/storybook-docs/index.html?path=/story/advanced-embedding-in-your-app--page).

But its not working because code inside useEffect **(new Landbot.Container)** is giving an error.

**Cannot find name 'Landbot'. Did you mean '_landbot'?**

I have used the command **npm install @landbot/core** for installing the landbot.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function MyLandbot({ url }) {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const _landbot = new Landbot.Container({
      container: containerRef.current,
      configUrl: url
    });

    return () => _landbot.destroy();
  }, [url, containerRef]);

  return <div className="MyLandbot" ref={containerRef} />;
}
```

If any one aware how to fix this issue then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I used **(window as any)** to prevent from getting this error.

As I had included a script related to Landbot in my index.html file. window will have access to Landbot object.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const Landbot = (window as any).Landbot
    const _landbot = new Landbot.Container({
        container: containerRef.current,
        configUrl: props.url
    });

    return () => _landbot.destroy();
}, [props.url, containerRef]);
```